# I can't pull my own repository, turns out I cannot ping github.com either

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ping

So when I try to pull my own github repository I get

> "ssh: Could not resolve hostname main: Name or service not known
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists."

The repository does exists and I'm pretty sure I do have acces rigths, since I configured my ssh keys following github's documentation and I even did it twice (deleting previous attempt)

The ssh key agent is working and the key is in my keychain, so just being curious I tried pinging github.com and a I get this:

> "PING github.com (20.201.28.151) 56(84) bytes of data.
> ^C
> --- github.com ping statistics ---
> 4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3146ms"
> Note that I can ping otther servers like google.com

Using the nslookup github.com command:

> "Server: 172.31.144.1
> Address: 172.31.144.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: github.com
Address: 20.201.28.151 "

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2.
i'd appreciate any help

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default?  Sometimes those program can block WSL from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your ssh error message:

> ```
> ssh: Could not resolve hostname main: Name or service not known
> ```

You're not trying to reach `github.com`.  You're trying to reach `main`.  But ssh has no idea who `main` is.

Check your Git and ssh configurations: make sure that your *URL* (as set in Git) refers to `github.com` rather than `main`, and then make sure your *ssh* configuration (in `$HOME/.ssh/config`) is not re-mapping host name `github.com` to `main`.

The lack of ping response is also suspicious, but you'll have to fix the ssh configuration issue before you can get to the next step.

Comment: The network issue overrides the configuration issue; it won't matter how `ssh` is configured if the network is unreachable in the first place. (The `ssh` error could simply be DNS lookup issue, not a problem with the `ssh` configuration itself.)

Comment: @chepner: it would still say "github.com" in the error message, if that were the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for helping, I just solved this by creating a directory (local of course), cloning my repo there and it just worked fine, I guess that there was a problem with the .git folder or something, not sure really but I solved it so...